# Stuck on if or loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, kali-linux

I was making a bash script for my Linux. But I am stuck on if or loop. If I select yes it's `spamming ==yes`.

```
 echo "Found a previously saved file. Do you want to continue with this? (Yes/No)"
    read Response
if [["$Response" == "Yes" || "$Response" == "yes" || "$Response" == "y" || "$Response" == "Y"]]; then
    echo "Success" 
    else
    echo "Fail"
    fi
```

Comment: What loop? There is no loop in your code.

Comment: @user1934428 Yet, it does indeed loop.

Comment: You can simplify this to `[[ $Response = [yY]?(es) ]]`.

Comment: The code snippet you posted can't loop.

Comment: @user1934428 I added an explanation for the loopy behavior to my answer.

Comment: It's not what programmers call a **loop**, at least not in your program. Your program does not loop. You invoke the program `yes`, and this program has, by design, a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space between `[[` and `"` and also between `"`and `]]`. You can also drop `"` around your strings when using `[[` and `]]` to test - but leave the space there. Otherwise, `bash` will do this:

```
[[yes == Yes
```

With the response:

```
[[yes: command not found...
```

The `||` makes it try the next part and it's here that it executes the command that becomes the "magical" loop:

```
yes == yes
```

`yes` is actually a command that will repeat what you give it as an argument (it defaults to `y` to be able to do `yes | program` to answer all questions that `program` asks with `y`). It will continue to repeat the same thing until `stdout` is closed (the receiver closes `stdin`).

So, it will print `== yes` in an endless stream.

Fix:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Found a previously saved file. Do you want to continue with this? (Yes/No)"
read -r Response

if [[ $Response == Yes || $Response == yes || $Response == y || $Response == Y ]]; then
    echo "Success" 
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

Comment: May be the double quote marks are not necessary here, but sometimes it happens the parameter is empty – then `$x = yes` may become ` = y` which is not a valid expression.

Comment: @CiaPan No, not with `[[` / `]]` - You're thinking of `[` / `]`. Try it:  `if [[ $empty1 == $empty2 ]]; then` (where both are empty or even undefined).

Comment: Thanks, @Ted ! You made me realize I have lived a good part of my life in error. Luckily, with no bad consequences! :D

Comment: Of course, a  `case` statement would be a lot more elegant and idiomatic here.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, or chepner's suggestion. `[[ $Response = [yY]?(es) ]]` is pretty nice too.